# Removing "a big" before using the word "fan"

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

I have heard someone says, e.g:

> - I am **a big** Elvis fan.
> - I am **a big** Obama fan.

But how it would be if someone tends to remove the determiner 'a' and the following adjective 'big'? I mean does it sound idiomatic in English to be said:

> - I am **an** Elvis fan.
> - I am **an** Obama fan.

Comment: No adjective is necessary. See the [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=an+Elvis+fan%2Ca+big+Elvis+fan%2Ca+huge+Elvis+fan%2Ca+fan+of+Elvis&year_start=1955&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=6). Try Googling "I'm a Beatles fan" (in quotes) and see what you get. You can also check Google books. (If you want, Google "and suddenly I was a Beatles fan" to get an excerpt from a book called _I'm Stalking Jake!_ and read through pages 3-4 to see how the author became a Beatles fan. It's pretty funny.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both

> I am a big Elvis fan.

and

> I am an Elvis fan.

are idiomatic. But the second form conveys a sense that the speaker's 'fandom' for Elvis is run-of-the-mill or nothing special. Yeah, I'm a fan of Elvis. No big deal. I'm also a fan of a million other things. Or, I'm an Elvis fan, but so are millions of other people. My fandom is not unique.  So, to me, somehow in this construction, a modifier lifts one from the blase/indifferent to out of the normal. My fandom of Elvis cannot be denied or assailed.

Also common is

> I am a huge Elvis fan.

and even

> I'm a humongous Elvis fan.

Interestingly, however,

> I'm a giant Elvis fan

sounds close to saying

> I am a fan of giant Elvis.

All the previous constructions do not seem to lend themselves as easily to this interpretation, and I am guessing that is because of how often they are used, and because *giant* is a noun. Note when we say

> I am a giant sports fan,

there is not much danger in interpreting the sentence to mean

> I am a fan of giant sports.

Answer (score 2):

Yes; that is idiomatic. It might be slightly more common to hear it in slight variant

> I am a fan of Elvis